# How to determine if variables from sockets match

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a node.js server and im using socket.io to communicate between two html pages.The two html pages send data across a socket, each page has an Entity associated with it e.g host is `Entity: 'Host'` and responder is vice versa.They both have a name associated with them which is the same to keep them 'paired' for a session e.g `Name: 'test'`.

When the server accepts these connections I have trouble finding out if there set. Currently what I have is:

```
socket.on('hostResponderStatus', function(msg)
    {
        if(msg.Status == 'Connecting')
        {
            if(msg.Entity == 'Host')
            {
                nameHost = msg.Name; //Grab the Name associated with the host
                socket.emit('StaringGL', {Status: 'Starting', Name: nameHost}); //Send back a socket stating gl is starting 
            }
            if(msg.Entity == 'Responder')
            {
                nameResponder = msg.Name; //Grab the Name associated with the responder
                socket.emit('StaringGL', {Status: 'Starting', Name: nameResponder}); //Send back a socket stating gl is starting 
            }
            if(msg.Name == nameHost && msg.Name == nameResponder) // if the names are the same start the child service
            {
                console.log("host name: "+nameHost);
                console.log("host name: "+nameResponder);
                var child_info = child.fork(__dirname + '/child_proccess/Child'); 
                child_info.send({Name: nameHost});
            }
        }
    });
```

But I dont think it ever reaches the last if statement because 'host' and 'responder' both go into there own if clauses and when they have finished the socket is never accessed again. I tried putting the if clause into the main body of the app.js like this:

```
if(nameHost == nameResponder)
{
    var child_info = child.fork(__dirname + '/child_proccess/Child'); 
    child_info.send({Name: nameHost});
}
```

but that will constantly fire when node is started due to both being null therefore equal. Is there a better way to check to see if the host and responder are ready?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you that, but the code logic is kinda messed up.

`msg.Entity` should have a value "Host" or "Responder", so variables `nameHost` and `nameResponder` will never be the same, because both are being set inside different if conditions.

And if you are trying to set `nameHost` and `nameResponder` outside the if conditions, both will be the same, because they are being assigned to the same object property `msg.Name`.

You really need to walk through the logic again.